# DAX_CALCULATE ()

Tags: filter, powerbi, max, dax, powerbi-desktop

This two Measures should give the same result but they don´t. Do you know why?

```
Total sales YTD Manual ID = 
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales Value],
    'Calendar'[CalendarYear] = MAX ( 'Calendar'[CalendarYear] )
        && 'Calendar'[ID] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[ID] )
)


Total Sales YTD Manual no FILTER = 
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales Value],
    'Calendar'[CalendarYear] = MAX ( 'Calendar'[CalendarYear] )
        && 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a special case when using date tables. The calculate statement is expanded internally to include a REMOVEFILTERS() on the whole date table. The following video describes it perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sETL5-enLEk

[image]

is expanded to:

[image]

which on a date table is expanded to

[image]

Comment: Thank for the video, it was quite self-explanatory, but not sure if answering the orginal question.  Still I don´t get it. The only change between both measures is -- 'Calendar'[ID] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[ID] ) -- Vs -- 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) --. The result should be the same, right?

Comment: Nope - there is a hidden removefilters() being introduced because you are using the date column.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved and/or upvote if it helped. Thanks

Comment: You mean this behaviour (hidden removefilters()) is because there is a "Date" column, not a "normal" one like ID?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you watch the video again, it explains it.